# path connected parts

Tags: real-analysis, path-connected

Let's say $P$ is a collection of path collected parts of $\mathbb{R^{p}}$, with the standard metric. We know that $\cap P\neq 0$. I want to prove that $\cup P$ is also path connected.

This is what I already have but I'm a little stuck with writing the rest of my idea down.

Take $x,y \in \cup P$ random. I'm going to prove that there exist a function $f\mapsto \cup P$ so that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$.
Define $P_{1},P_{2}\subset \cup P$ with $x \in P_{1}$ and $y\in P_{2}$.
Because $\cap P$ isn't empty there is an $z\in \cap P$. This implies that $z\in P_{1}$ and $z \in P_{2}$.
Because $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ are path connected parts (given) there are functions $h:[0,1] \mapsto P_{1}$ and $g:[0,1]\mapsto P_{2}$ so that $h(0)=x$ and $h(1)=z$ and $g(0)=z$ and $g(1)=y$.

My idea for the rest is that i can write $f$ as $g$ and $h$ but I'm not sure how to do that. I wanted to change $h$ into $h:[0,1/2] \mapsto P_{1}$ and $g$ to $g:[1/2,1] \mapsto P_{2}$.
Can someone help me to write the rest of my solution down.

EDIT: I think i can defini f so that
$f:[0,1]\mapsto\cup P$ with f(x)=g(2x) for $x \in [0,1/2[$ and f(x)=h(2x-1) for $x \in [1/2,1]$

Then I only needed to verify that $f$ is a continuous bijection. But because f is a composition of two continuous bijections it's okej.
But does this prove that $\cup P$ is also pad connected?

EDIT 2:
Now i prove that f is continuous in 1/2

Let's take the right limit of x->1/2
lim(f(x))=g(1)=z
let's take the left limit of x->1/2
lim(f(x))=h(0)=z

so continuous in 1/2

Comment: $f(t)=h(2t)$ for $t\leq 1/2$, $f(t)=g(2(t-1/2))$ for $t>1/2$.

Comment: but then is f(0)=h(0)=y

Comment: Oh, right, I gave the path in the other direction, sorry. But reversing a path's direction is as easy as replacing $t$ by $1-t$.

Comment: is it a good idea like I edited?

Comment: Wait, my first version was correct. You said $h(0)=x$, not $y$. Your edit is correct if you switch the roles of $h$ and $g$. Technically speaking, you still need to prove that $f$ is continuous at $1/2$. But that's not hard. And then the proof of path-connectedness is done.

Comment: ow okej thank you

Comment: Maybe a tiny remark to a choice of word you used, $f$ is not a composition $h\circ g$ of two maps. This would indeed be continuous as well. It is rather a, you could say, concatenation of two paths, which is often denoted as $h*g$ or something like that, which is again continuous, as you have shown.

Comment: thank you, I don't speak english normaly so it's nice that you help me :) thanks

Comment: Your proof is correct.